# Why are the values that my Gyroscope Sensor returns are always zero?

Tags: android, sensors

```
 if (timestamp != 0) {
                final float dT = (event.timestamp - timestamp) * NS2S;
                // Axis of the rotation sample, not normalized yet.
                double axisX = event.values[0];
                double axisY = event.values[1];
                double axisZ = event.values[2];
}
timestamp = event time
```

I would like to read the values on 3 axis. But the values that sensor returns are always zero

Comment: I do not understand the problem, I do not see any code that I can debug, I do not know what you did and where you are stuck. Please read [ask] and edit your question to allow us to write a good answer ;)

Comment: I am sorry that the code misses something. I would like to gain the angles in each axis, so it has to be double axisX = event.values[0]*dT, and the values are 0.0